# Ingenico .net SDK Integration - Unauthorized and Connection Closed exception while making any API Call

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, integration, payment-gateway

I am new to ingenico payment integration. I have created new Sandbox account and Installed the SDK nuget into Console application.

I am trying below api,

```
GET https://{domainname}/v1/{merchantId}/services/testconnection
```

to test the connection. If the Connection gets completed i wanted to create the new hosted checkout.

```
POST https://{domainname}/v1/{merchantId}/hostedcheckouts
```

But whenever I have Tried to connect using the .net sdk it throws below exceptions
1) An error occurred while sending the request.
2) The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
3) Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

I am using `eu.sandbox.api-ingenico.com` endpoint.

Can anyone help me to get through this exceptions? and also Is there any forum or Blogs for sdk integration or Ingenico developer community.?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Are you getting that response when doing test connection or hostedcheckouts?

Comment: Hello, Thank You for the Response. I am getting the response when making any api call to Ingenico, i.e. for both Test connection and Hosted Checkout.

Comment: This strongly sounds like a networking issue and that it's not even reaching Ingenico. If I use a made-up merchant id and use curl to hit https://eu.sandbox.api-ingenico.com/v1/12345/services/testconnection I get JSON back saying I have MISSING_OR_INVALID_AUTHORIZATION, which I'd expect. I'd investigate what the error you see means on its own. There are lots of Stackoverflow questions about it.

Comment: If I am using the same curl I am Getting the same error as You get. "MISSING_OR_INVALID_AUTHORIZATION". Even I Have checked the .net SDK source code, They have mentioned as If Authorization failed it throws the same exception which i get and mentioned above in the questions. So There is no any Networking or Reaching issue. I think they are not providing support for my country (INDIA) hope that I am wrong.

Comment: I would contact them (https://www.ingenico.com/contact-us/epayments). I'd be surprised if their SDK triggered some security but curl by-passed it. I would still expect some kind of set up issue

Comment: If you resolve it, answer your own question. It may help other .net users of Ingenico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was literally laughing on my self, The issue was I have created the Sandbox account by selecting Region "Asia Pacific" When I create another account by selecting the "Europe, Middle East, Africa" and used the API Key and API Secret, The Issue Gets Resolved.

They are not providing support for Asian Region for sandbox account.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

For people having the **MISSING_OR_INVALID_AUTHORIZATION** error, in my case it was an **expired API Key Id and Secret**.